# PRAW: serializing Comment and Submission objects as JSON

Tags: python, json, praw

I'm currently working on a reddit crawler using praw for some data mining purposes. I would like to crawl comments and submissions from subreddits and then save them in a database or file, preferably in a json format for use later. 
I am having trouble trying to serialize the comment and submission objects as JSON objects in python. Is there an existing method or way to do this? 
Note: I am also pretty new to python.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE ---------

Looks like this is no longer possible, hat tip to Antoine

### https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/701

I'm not sure if there's a way to serialize what you need but you can save the submission ids with:

```
some_id = sub.id
```

and then retrieve them later on with

```
r.get_submission(submission_id=some_id)
```

EDIT -----------------------------------------

So did a bit of research and found this: https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/271

So essentially you can turn on storing json with:

```
r.config.store_json_result = True
```

You can then access the json data with the json_dict member of the comment or submission.

Comment: Ah, I would like to preferably save the entire submission instead, so I would only need to crawl new comments the next time round

Comment: fantastic, thanks! I saw the property in the object but it was always None, didnt know that I could turn a setting on

Comment: Yeah I saw that too and it was bugging me, so I looked through github. Glad to help.

Comment: Anyone seeing this now should know that it's now longer available: https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/701